# Shorten or extend xypic arrows

Tags: diagrams, arrows, xy-pic

In an `xypic` or `xymatrix` diagram, is it possible to specify that an arrow should only cover part of the distance it normally would?  In other words, for an arrow  `\xymatrix{ A \ar[r] & B }`, or between two nodes in a more complex diagram `\ar@{>=>}"A";"B"`, I would like to specify that e.g. it should start at 0.3 of the distance from A to B, and end at 0.85 of the distance to B.

(This would be similar to what the `\xymatrix{ A \ar[r(0.6)] & B }` notation does, except that that only shortens the arrow on the target end, not the source.)

Comment: Well, try `tikz-cd` instead. It's easier to shorten arrows in `tikz`.

Comment: @LeoLiu: I like `tikz-cd`, but I have co-authors who prefer to stick to `xymatrix` where possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do this is to first typeset an empty arrow `\ar@{}[r]` and label the required positions.  For example `^(0.4){}="a"` places an empty label named "a" at `0.4` of the way along the arrow.  If you have set up labels "a" and "b" this way, then `\ar "a";"b"` will draw an arrow between them.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

Normal arrow
\begin{equation}
  \xymatrix{ A \ar[r] & B }
\end{equation}
Shortened arrow
\begin{equation}
  \xymatrix{ A \ar@{}[r]^(.25){}="a"^(.75){}="b" \ar "a";"b"& B }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this in LyX and got `<pos> "a" not defined"` and `<pos> "b" not defined`. How do I fix it?

Comment: @Exterior Sounds like a LyX specific problem.  You should ask a separate question.

Comment: latexmk also gives an error: Use of \next@ doesn't match its definition. [}];  Missing } inserted, and others.

Comment: @FoscoLoregian It compiles fine for me on an up-to-date distribution.  You should ask a separate question posting more details of the error messages.